# Inequalities proof by math induction

Tags: inequality, induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I have some troubles with inequalities proof by math induction.

Let's consider an example. Prove by induction that the following is true:

$$ N^2 - 3 * N \ge 0, where: N \ge 0$$

Base: $$0-0 \ge 0, true$$

Induction:

$$ (N+1)^2 - 3 * (N+1) \ge 0 $$
$$ N^2 + 2 * N + 1 - 3 * (N + 1) \ge 0 $$
$$ N^2 + 2 * N + 1 - 3 * N - 3 \ge 0 $$
$$ N^2 + 2 * N - 3 * N - 2 \ge 0 $$

let's rearrange terms and add brackets:

$$ [N^2 - 3 * N] + [2 * N - 2] \ge 0 $$

**Is it right to say that (I don't understand why it is correct)** Expression in left brackets greater or equal to 0 according to our assumption.

Let's prove expression in right brackets. Check it for 0: 
$$ 2 * N - 2 \ge 0$$
$$ 2 * 0 - 2 \ge 0$$
$$ 0 \ge 2:false$$

Therefore, the following expression is false:

$$ N^2 - 3 * N \ge 0, where: N \ge 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It false because it false for $n=1$.

Id est, the statement $$P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$$ is wrong for $n=0$.

Here $P(n)$: for any integer $n\geq0$ we have $n^2-3n\geq0.$

But for $n\geq3$ it's true by your work.

I like the following way.

For $n=3$ it's true.

Let $n^2-3n\geq0$ be true for any $n\geq3$.

Thus, $$(n+1)^2-3(n+1)=n^2-n-2=n^2-3n+2n-2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: If it's already true for any $n\gt3$, then the inductive step is unnecessary!

Comment: @JMP Yes of course. But the topic-starter wants a proof by induction. By the way, it's true for any $n\geq3.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you, and I agree with you. But my point is what if we have a task to prove exact for N >= 0. 

I mean I could create an inequalities that will be true for N = 0, and true for N = 123143234534 and after, but false in between. And it will be hard for you to gues that inequalities is true starting for N = 123143234534, as you did with N = 3.

Comment: @No Name QA I added something. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you! According to your answer new question arises: Is it possible to create an expression or inequality that will be true for 1 but false for 2 and  then true 3,4, ...?

Comment: @No Name QA Yes, of course! Do you want to think about it  by yourself or to give an example?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It would be nice to have an example :)

Comment: For example: $2^n\geq 3n-1$. For $n=1$ it's true. For $n=2$ it's wrong and for any $n\geq3$ it's true.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you so much!

Comment: @No Name QA You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is show that the statement:

$$N^2-3N\ge0\;\;\text{ where}\;\;N\ge0$$

is false.

It is true for $N\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,3)$, or for just $N^2$ for example.